# Postgresql - Stops listening after mounting volume to data directory

Tags: postgresql, remote-access, disk-volume

I have a temporary need for a 180GB postgresql database.  For costs sake, I have this on a cheap 40GB disk server and I want to mount a 200GB volume to the postgresql data directory.

My problem: After I stop postgresql, mount the volume, copy contents, update postgresql.conf, start postgresql, it stops listening on `5432`

My Question: Why does this happen?

My order of operations:

1. netstat and see that postgres is listening on 5432 for any remote connections

   ```
   root@foobar:/etc/postgresql/9.5/main# netstat -tulpen
   Active Internet connections (only servers)
   Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      112        44384       25831/postgres  
   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3451            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          94839       15010/sshd      
   tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      112        44385       25831/postgres  
   tcp6       0      0 :::3451                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          94848       15010/sshd
   ```

then

2. stop postgresql
3. make a new directory /mnt/whatever
4. mount /dev/xvdb to /mnt/whatever/
5. Copy contents of '/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/' into new volume '/mnt/whatever'
6. Edit postgresql.conf and change "data directory" to new volume..

   ```
   data_directory = '/mnt/whatever'         # use data in another directory
                                            # (change requires restart)
   hba_file = '/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf'       # host-based authentication file
                                            # (change requires restart)
   ident_file = '/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_ident.conf'   # ident configuration file
                                            # (change requires restart)
   ```
7. Start postgresql
8. netstat and find that postgresql is no longer listening on 5432

   ```
   root@foobar:/# netstat -tulpen
   Active Internet connections (only servers)
   Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3451            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          94839       15010/sshd       
   tcp6       0      0 :::3451                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          94848       15010/sshd
   ```

At first I thought that it was something in the `postgresql.conf` that I messed up allowing remote connections, but after rebuilding the server several times going through this process, it definitely listens on `5432` all the way up until I mount the new volume.
Postgresql works fine remotely until I mount a volume and update the data dir in the conf.  Also, it won't start listening even after I unmount the volume and restore a backup of the original `postgresql.conf`.  It seems to me that something I'm doing in the mount is breaking it.
I have made a rule allowing `5432` in IPtables, but that doesn't fix it (and remember, remote connections work fine before the mount, so I don't think its firewall).

Any suggestions?

My guess is that its some kind of `lsof` thing, but I'm stuck.

Comment: Looking at the logfile of postgresql could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 5) Copy contents of '/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/' into new volume
>   '/mnt/whatever'

The most plausible reason why, after doing that, PostgreSQL fails immediately on startup, would be that this step does not keep the exact permissions/owners of files and directories that get copied.
If you use `cp`, make sure to add the `-p` option.

> 7) Start postgresql
>
> 8) netstat and find that postgresql is no longer listening on 5432

You seem to search for a network problem but not listening on port 5432 is more likely to be due to PostgreSQL exiting immediately in error after step #7. As mentioned in the comments, check the postgresql logs: the reason why it fails to start should be written explicitly there. Typically the logs are in `/var/log/postgresql/` (given the paths mentioned it looks like a Debian system).

Comment: Thank you!! So simple, it was permissions!  I created the new directory as "root:root" instead of "postgres:postgres", fixing permissions fixes the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: @P-Didz: You're welcome! Please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if your're satisfied with it.